# Bash script failing

Tags: bash, ssh

I'm writing a script which purpose is to connect to a number of servers and create an account. The "core" is:

```
ssh user@ip
sudo su -
useradd -m -p 123 $1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
   echo "$1 successfully created on ip."
fi
chage -d 0 $1
chown -R $1 /home/$1

exit #exit root
exit #exit the server
```

I have established a private-public key relationship between the servers in order to be able to perform the ssh without being prompted for the password, however, when I run the script it does the ssh but then doesn't perform the next commands on the target machine. Instead, when manually exiting from the target server, I see that those commands were executed (or better said, tried to be executed) on the local machine.

Comment: You'd better do `ssh user@ip -c "useradd..."`

Comment: @mbratch solved with that question. `ssh -l user ip "script"`

Answer (score 0):

It won't work this way. You shoudl do it like:

1. `ssh user@ip 'yourcommands ; listed ; etc.'` or
2. copy the script you want to execute on the servers via `scp /your/scriptname user@ip:/tmp/` then execute it `ssh user@ip 'sh /tmp/yourscriptname'`

But you are starting another script when starting `sudo`.

Now you have (at least) two options:

1. `ssh user@ip 'sudo -s -- "yourcommands ; listed ; etc."'` or
2. copy the part after the `sudo` to a different script, then:

   ```
   ssh user@ip 'sudo -s -- "sh differentscript"'`
   ```

Comment: I don't know why but the `sudo su -` is not working. For example, `ssh user@ip 'ls -la'`works and shows the ls of the user's home, but `ssh user@ip 'sudo su - ; ls -la'` does not return anything, I got to finish it by CTRL+C. It's not a privilege issue, as I can manually do `ssh user@ip` and then `sudo su -`

Comment: `ls -la` doesn't run until the shell started by `sudo su -` completes.

Answer (score 0):

So there should be no asking password when run both `ssh` and `sudo` command

```
ssh user@ip bash -c "'
sudo su -
useradd -m -p 123 $1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
   echo "$1 successfully created on ip."
fi
chage -d 0 $1
chown -R $1 /home/$1

exit #exit root
exit #exit the server
'"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to `sudo` why don't you just ssh as root: `root@ip`? Just do:

```
ssh root@ip 'command1; command2; command3'
```

In your case if you want to be sure they are all successfull in order to proceed:

```
ssh root@ip 'USER=someUser; useradd -m -p 123 $USER && chage -d 0 $USER && chown -R $USER /home/$USER'
```

**EDIT:**

If the root access is not alowed if would do the following:

1. Create the script with the commands you want to execute on the remote machine, for instance `script.sh`:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   USER=someUser 
   useradd -m -p 123 $USER && chage -d 0 $USER && chown -R $USER /home/$USER
   ```
2. Copy the script to the remote machine:

   ```
   scp script.sh user@ip:/destination/dir
   ```
3. Invoke it remotely:

   ```
   ssh user@ip 'sudo /destination/dir/script.sh'
   ```

EDIT2:

Other option without creating any files:

```
ssh user@ip "sudo bash -c 'USER=someUser && useradd -m -p 123 $USER && chage -d 0 $USER && chown -R $USER /home/$USER'"
```

Comment: root access is not allowed.

Comment: made and edit to my answer.

Comment: that's the same Zsolt Botykai said on his point #2. My boss doesn't want that, he wants to "centralize" the scripts on a machine.

Comment: I don't understant what does "centralize the script on the machine" mean? So what would you like to achieve?

Comment: edited again, hope that this is what you need.